# Global variables and struct arrays

Tags: c, struct, calloc

I need a global structure, which defines an array of Queues. I want to use pointers for educational purposes.
Inside a.h I defined the struct Queue:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
    int size;
    q_elem *root;
    q_elem *last;
} Queue;
```

and the external variable

```
extern Queue **queue;
```

a.c has the function Queue* queue_new() to create a new queue.

now b.c uses the global variable Queue **queue; and I want to create an array of queues.

What I tried was:

```
queue = calloc(num_queues, sizeof(Queue*));
int i;
for(i=0; i < num_queues; i++){
    queue[i] = queue_new();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work correctly when I check inside my debugger. What am I doing wrong?

```
Queue* queue_new() {

    Queue *newQ = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    if (newQ == NULL)
        return NULL;
    *newQ = (Queue) {0, NULL, NULL};
    return newQ;
}
```

Comment: How does it not work correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't seem to work correctly when I check inside my debugger_ ?

Comment: I think that probably you have something wrong in queue_new()

Comment: When I check inside the debugger what **queue looks like, I only see one queue, not multiple. I'll edit in the new() funct.

Comment: Please don't use global variables for educational purposes, at least not until you teach information hiding techniques and modules.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way. My problem is that my homework has preset void functions and I don't know how else I should operate on an instance of queue in another .c file. I'm not teaching, I'm learning.

Comment: `one queue, not multiple.` check `num_queues`

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but too big for comments.

I see nothing *wrong*, I think your problem is elsewhere in code.
Just many questionable things about this as an FYI.

1.As @Rohan said, how is it not working?

2.`int size;` should be `size_t size;`.

3.OP has not shown `Queue **queue;`  I assume there is a `Queue **queue;`  *someplace*.  Being in static space, it will get initialized to 0.  Better to explicitly initialize it to `NULL`.

4."... create an array of queues" is really " create an array of queues pointers".

5.Interesting you had a `NULL` check with `malloc()`, but not with `queue = calloc()`.

6.`int i;` should be `size_t i;`

7.`Queue *newQ = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));`: the cast `(Queue*)` is not needed.

8.Suggest `Queue *newQ = malloc(sizeof(*newQ));` instead.

9.`Queue* queue_new()` should be `Queue* queue_new(void)`.

10.Where is `num_queues` defined and initialized?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

The only thing you did wrong is how you interpreted your debugger's output.

> When I check inside the debugger what **queue looks like, I only see
>   one queue, not multiple.

You only see one queue because that's what `**queue` is, since `queue` is just a pointer to one pointer to a `Queue` (the type of `queue` is `struct Queue **`); `queue`'s type doesn't convey the information that after the first one there are more `Queue` pointers, and so the debugger has no reason to print more.

If by chance your debugger is GDB, you could use a loop to print all queues:

```
(gdb) set $i = 0       
(gdb) while ($i < num_queues)   
 >p *queue[$i++]  
 >end
```

You could even define a command for that purpose:

```
(gdb) define pp
Type commands for definition of "pp".
End with a line saying just "end".
>set $i = 0       
>while ($i < $arg1)
 >p *$arg0[$i++] 
 >end           
>end           
(gdb) pp queue num_queues
```